# QChar get digit value if `isDigit()`

Tags: c++, qt, qchar

How to get the digits value elegantly?

```
QChar qc('4');
int val=-1;
if(qc.isDigit()){
   val = qc.toLatin1() - '0';
}
```

does not look that good.

Neither does converting to `QString` since creating a QString object and start parsing just for this purpose seems to be overkill.

```
QChar qc('4');
int val=-1;
if(qc.isDigit()){
   val = QString(qc).toInt();
}
```

Any better options or interfaces that I have missed?

Comment: QString::toInt()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method `int QChar::digitValue() const` [which](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#digitValue):

> returns the numeric value of the digit, or -1 if the character is not
>   a digit.

So, you can write:

```
QChar qc('4');
int val = qc.digitValue();
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that!? Thanks